# Symfony2 redirect in an ajax action

Tags: ajax, symfony, redirect

I am using Symfony2 and in my register.html.twig, I have:

```
var registerdata= {
                    "email": email,
                    "pwd": pwd,
                    "phoneNum": phoneNum
                    };
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "register",
                    data: registerdata,
                    success: function(msg){

                        alert("OK! ");
                    },
                    error: function(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){

                        alert("Failed! ");
                    }
                });
```

In my controller, after inserting those data into the database, I want to redirect to the login page, and I have code like this:

```
try
    {
        $this -> insertData($account);
        return $this ->redirect($this ->generateUrl('login'));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return new response('Message: '. $e->getMessage());
    }
```

It does not work, however. How should I handle the problem?

Comment: Server redirections should not be done in Ajax calls. Do the redirection in the jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another more step in your jQuery code. When the server returns a redirect response, you should redirect the client using javascript:

```
var registerdata= {
    "email": email,
    "pwd": pwd,
    "phoneNum": phoneNum
    };
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "register",
    data: registerdata,
    success: function(msg){

        alert("OK! ");
    },
    error: function(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown){

        alert("Failed! ");
    },
    complete: function(xhr)
    {
        if (xhr.status == 302) {
            location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
        }
    }
});
```

Of course this is far from ideal.